# node.js reqest.js/cheerio.js returning empty json

Tags: node.js, callback, cheerio

I'm working on an app that scrapes a website and exposes data as a rest api. Im using Node, Express, request, cheerio. I seem to be getting the correct values in the array..but just before returning..the array is still empty (out side the request function scope )

I could not workout what I'm missing..could you please take a look at my code and let me know?

in app.js I specified the route,

```
    app.use('/timetable', timetable.timetable(url));
```

in timetable.js

```
var classes = require('../lib/classes');
var schedule = require('../lib/schedule');
exports.timetable = function(timeTableURL) {

return function(req, res) {

    request( timeTableURL, function srapeWebsite(error, response, html ) {
        var webHtml = '';
        var moreInfo = []; 
        if( !error && response.statusCode === 200 ) {
            webHtml = cheerio.load(html);
        }
        // schedule.getInfo returns an array of json objects where
        // json = {
        //    day,
        //    number,
        //    url
        // }
        var info = schedule.getInfo(webHtml);

        for (var index = 0; index < info.length; index++) {     
            var json = info[index];
            classes.getMoreInfo(json, function (moreInfoJson) {
                //console.log shows correct information here
                moreInfo.push(moreInfoJson);
            };
        }
        // however moreInfo is empty here..hence not getting anything
        res.json(moreInfo);
    } );
  };
};
```

Ideas is, for each of the json object in the array, get more information from the url specified.

so the end result would be,

```
    finalJson = {
       day : ''
       json : []
    }
```

in classes.js

```
exports.getMoreInfo =  function (info, callback) {

var infoDay = info.day;
var infoNumber = parseInt(info.number);
var moreInfoURL = info.moreInfoUrl;
var stuff = [];

var moreInfo = {};
moreInfo.day = infoDay;
moreInfo.json = [];

if (infoNumber > 0 ) {
    request(moreInfoURL, function(error, response,html) {
        var moreInfoHtml = '';
        if( !error && response.statusCode === 200 ) {
            moreInfoHtml = cheerio.load(html) ;

        }
        var $ = moreInfoHtml;

        $('table tbody tr').each ( function getWhatisNeeded () {
            var json = getJson ( $(this) );
            stuff.push(json);

        });

        moreInfo.json = stuff;
        return callback(moreInfo);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip 'jonjon'..I used Async.map to fix it ( sorry was going to post it yesterday..but you beat me to it)..I'll also try out Promises as well..I might as well learn both techniques..

this is what I did to fix it..

In app.js

```
app.get('/timetable', timetable.timetable);
```

In timetable.js

```
var url = '...';
exports.timetable = function ( request, response ) {

    //scrape html to get info
    scrape.getHtml( url, function ( error, html ) {
    // schedule.getInfo returns an array of json objects where
    // json = {
    //    day,
    //    number,
    //    url
    // }
    var info = schedule.getInfo(cheerio.load(html));

    //getmoreinfo
    async.map(info, classes.getMoreInfo, function( error,moreInfo ) {
        if(!error) {
            response.json(moreInfo);
        }else {
            response.send("error encountered");
        }
    });
  });
}
```

In classes.js

```
   exports.getMoreInfo =  function (info, callback) {

   var infoDay = info.day;
   var infoNumber = parseInt(info.number);
   var moreInfoURL = info.moreInfoUrl;
   var stuff = [];

   var moreInfo = {};
   moreInfo.day = infoDay;
   moreInfo.json = [];

   if (infoNumber > 0 ) {
   request(moreInfoURL, function(error, response,html) {
    var moreInfoHtml = '';
    if( !error && response.statusCode === 200 ) {
        moreInfoHtml = cheerio.load(html) ;

    }
    var $ = moreInfoHtml;

    $('table tbody tr').each ( function getWhatisNeeded () {
        var json = getJson ( $(this) );
        stuff.push(json);

    });

    moreInfo.json = stuff;
    return callback(null, moreInfo);
  });
 }
}
```

I'm getting what I'm after now..however it seems to take 5 seconds..will need to test more anyway..

Answer (score 3):

Your call to classes.getMoreInfo is async.

What happens is that you do not wait for the call to return, and call res.json with an empty array.

EDIT:
How to resolve this issue? one approach is to use promisses (see for example https://github.com/malko/D.js).

getMoreInfo should return a deferred object:

```
exports.getMoreInfo =  function (info) {
    var deferred = D();
    ...
    request(..., function(){
        deferred.resolve(moreInfo);
    });
    ...
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and timetable.js should look more or less like this:

```
var promises = [];
for (var index = 0; index < info.length; index++) {     
    var json = info[index];
    promises.push(classes.getMoreInfo(json));
}
D.all(promises).this(function(array_of_results){
    res.json(array_of_results);
}
```

I did not test the code, so I might have a bug here, but this is a good guideline on how to resolve async issues in node.js and in general.
Get your self familiar with promises, it will be much easier to solve problems like this.